# jQuery, radio button getting value

Tags: jquery

Hay, how can i get the value of this? i.e. which one is selected.

```
<input type='radio' name="thing" value="on" checked>
<input type='radio' name="thing" value="off">
```

I cant get the value with

```
$("input[name='thing']").val()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
$("input[name='thing']:checked").val()
```

Comment: The @ style is deprecated in jQuery 1.3 and won't work, ref: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeHas#attribute

Comment: Edited it... didn't look like the author was gonna change it.

Answer (score 1):

solution is found

```
$("input[name='thing']:checked").val()
```