# jQuery throwing error when trying to get selected radio button value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this radio button set:

```
<div id="reviewScope">
  <input type="radio" name="loadMarkers" id="day" value="day"><label for="day">24 Hours</label>
  <input type="radio" name="loadMarkers" id="week" value="week"><label for="week">Week</label>
  <input type="radio" name="loadMarkers" id="month" value"month"><label for="month">Month</label>
</div>
```

Then calling using jQuery 1.5.2, I'm trying to get the value of the selected radio button following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006829/jquery-radio-button-getting-value):

```
$('#reviewScope input:radio').change(function() {
  period = $("input[name='loadMarkers']:checked").val();
  ....
}
```

Firebug is throwing the error:

**$("input[name='loadMarkers']:checked").val is not a function**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mu. I don't think the change handler would ever run if that was the case, and that's where the error is

Comment: Are you using a mix of jQuery and some other js framework? (like the wordpress admin). If that's the case, try replacing $ with jQuery.

Comment: Oddly, if I change to `period = $("input[name='loadMarkers']:checked").val()` to `period = $(this).attr('value')` it works.  I tried removing the line completely and added `console.log($)` but nothing appeared to be logged in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the closing ')' in the change method?

```
$('#reviewScope input:radio').change(function() {
  period = $("input[name='loadMarkers']:checked").val();
  ....
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67Q68/

Comment: That's just a copy and paste error on my part. Actual code has the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#day").click(function() {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
     var period = "day";
    }
});
```

Do the same as for other radio buttons one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('#reviewScope input:radio').each(function() {
   $(this).click(function() {
       period = $("input[name='loadMarkers']:checked").val();
       ....
   });
});
```

Check for closing parenthesis and brackets